# How to add an application shortcut in dock on mac machine?

Tags: macos

I was just struggling to add an icon of application into the dock on my mac machine, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just drag and drop and if you want programmatically it better to specify in your question and also refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Finder > Applications > {Your Application} > Press Control + Shift + Command + T

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

- Open the app you want to add.
- find the app using Spotlight-press 'Command + Space'and type the name of the app.
- Right-click or control-click on the icon in the dock.
- From the options that appear choose Options > Keep in Dock.
- Done! You can go and chill for an instance :)